# Email pipe to php script working only sometimes

Tags: php, linux, apache, pipe

I have a php pipe script that receives an email, takes an attached *.csv from it and parses it.

However, when the email is sent from where it is supposed to be coming from, it silently errors. But when I take that same email and resend it from my address it goes through just fine. is there any simple reason it could be doing this?

Comment: Is there anything in the php error log?

Comment: Do you have the proper Hashbang for your PHP and is it running PHP CLI?

Comment: yes proper hash bang, and no errors in the error_log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try and save some information about the email in a logfile before anything else, then some more info as you parse it. This way you get a more better understanding of what is happening

Comment: that found what's happening; for some reason it is not recognizing the attachment when it is coming from the external source.

Comment: can't you access the email adress in a webmail client to see if you can read it there ?

Answer (score 0):

Is the email youa re sending from a real email? There may be a setting that allows emails to be sent from a valid user.

What happens if you chown the script to be the user you want to send the email from.  Does it work then?

Comment: both the email addresses are real addresses, and there's only one user on the server, so I don't understand what you mean by chowning the script.

Comment: I just understood what you meant; I'm not sending messages from the server, I'm sending an emil into the server, and the server parses the email.